# javascript to determine the ending of mp3 song in embed tag

Tags: javascript, embed

I wanted to know if there is any way to determine the duration of my mp3 song through javascript so that I could play the next song in the embed tag according to the ending time of the first song in embed tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. `<embed>` has no standard API to get any information about the embedded content. Use an `<audio>` element if you want that sort of data.

Comment: What attribute of audio tag to use to achieve such kind of information??

Comment: Attribute? You're waiting for an event, use an event listener. `element.addEventListener('ended', func);`